# Creating a Report on Flow Orchestrations

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow orchestration that I am using to track progress of a process in my system. I would like to report on the average duration on certain stages. These can easily be found on the Orchestration Run Log but are nowhere to be found on the custom report type Orchestration Run.

Does anyone know a workaround or a way to report on the average durations of particular stages, or even steps if possible?

Comment: Hey there! Just updating this as I found this link to a [Salesforce Architects roadmap](https://architect.salesforce.com/roadmaps/roadmap-explorer?product=Flow+Orchestration#:~:text=Flow%20Orchestration-,Reporting,-GA) saying they will add this feature in early 2024. Will update the answer once it's implemented!